# Как добавить в запрос условие: "но не более 3 книг одного автора за одну дату"?

Tags: mysql

Есть таблица books:

book_id | date | autor_id | book_name

1 | 2022-10-10 | 3 | Робинзон Крузо

2 | 2022-10-10 | 2 | Буратино

3 | 2022-10-10 | 3 | 12 стульев

4 | 2022-10-10 | 1 | Плоский мир

5 | 2022-10-10 | 3 | Психология

На главной странице сайта я вывожу последние добавленные книги. Но постепенно выяснилось, что у авторов очень неравномерное количество книг, добавляемых ежедневно: например у автора 3 сегодня добавлено 100 книг, а у авторов 1 и 2 - всего по 5 книг. Из-за этого книги автора 3 забивают всю выдачу на главной странице, а книги остальных авторов просто теряются в этой массе.

Сейчас запрос для выборки книг на главную страницу выглядит так:
SELECT * FROM `books` ORDER BY `date` DESC LIMIT 50;

Как можно составить запрос так, чтобы добавилось условие: "но не более 3 книг одного автора за одну дату"?

Comment: Точная версия MySQL?

Comment: Server version: 10.3.29-MariaDB

Comment: Тогда тупо ROW_NUMBER в CTE и WHERE rn<=3 в основном запросе. PS. Не забудьте сформулировать и закодить чёткий критерий отбора 3 книг из всех имеющихся.

Comment: Akina, благодарю - ваш ответ помог.